# Evaluate $\int \int \vec{f} . \hat{n} \ \ ds$ using stokes theorem

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

Consider $\vec{f} = (2x-y)\hat{i} - yz^2 \hat{j} -yz^2 \hat{k}$ where $S$ is the upper half of the surface of the sphere $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 = 1$ and C is its boundary

$Stoke's$ Theorem :Let $S$ be a piecewise smooth surface bounded by piecewise smooth simple curve $C$ and $\vec{f}(x,y,z)$ be a continous vector function which has continous first order partial derivatives in a region of space which contains $S$. Then $\int_C \vec{f} . d\vec{r}  = \int \int_S curl \vec{f} . \hat{n} ds $

> > My Question is : I want to ask that what is C which is the boundary of the surface S

Comment: The unit circle on the $xy$-plane (i.e. $x^2+y^2 = 1, z = 0$ )

Comment: Surface area eclosed this circle is area of the circle which is not equal to $S$

Comment: Given any curve, there are infinitely many surfaces having that curve as boundary. For the unit circle $\{ (x,y,z) : x^2+y^2 = 1, z = 0 \}$, the unit disk $\{ (x,y,z) : x^2+y^2 \le 1, z = 0 \}$ is one, the upper hemisphere $\{ (x,y,z) : x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1, z \ge 0 \}$ is another.

Comment: Is the Stoke's Theorem hold on all the sulfaces having that curve as a boundary.

Comment: yes, Stoke's theorem holds on all surfaces having that curve as a boundary. This also means the surface integral $\int_S \nabla\times\vec{f}$ is independent of where the "interior" part of surface $S$ are (as long as $\nabla \times \vec{f} = \vec{0}$ there).

Comment: Achille thanks for commenting

Comment: Oops, ignore the part "(as long as $\nabla \times \vec{f} = \vec{0}$)" in my previous comment, that is non-sense.